# How to subtract Textbox with listbox items

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

Hy Everyone
How to subtract Listbox item With Textbox On Button press
listbox first item sutract with textbox1
and listbox 2nd item subtract with textbox2
and so on
here my code its work but so lengthy

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TextBox1.Text = CDbl(ListBox1.Items.Item(0)) - CDbl(TextBox1.Text)
TextBox2.Text = CDbl(ListBox1.Items.Item(1)) - CDbl(TextBox2.Text)
```

End Sub
and so on
Please help

Comment: No one can Understand My last Question So i Edited And post it in Simple Words

Comment: If you want less lengthy code rename those controls to something less lengthy.

Comment: Bro I want Ultimated Quantity So if I write every thing my code is So lengthy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with `For Loop`, but make sure the number of `TextBoxes`equals to the `ListBox` items:

```
For iIndex As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
    Result = CDbl(Me.ListBox1.Items(iIndex)) - CDbl(Me.Controls.Item("TextBox" & iIndex + 1).Text)
Next
```